# Frequently Querying the DMV - sys.dm_exec_sessions, sys.dm_exec_connections and sys.dm_exec_requests

Tags: sql-server, dmv

Could frequently (e.g. 5 seconds) querying the below DMVs from a custom tool to get the connection info impact performance on SQL server? I understand this would give a snapshot at that point.
SQL audit logs probably the best way to get this info but It would help if I get any guidance based on your experience with the DMV.

```
select sys.dm_exec_sessions.session_id, host_name as [Connecting machine name], client_net_address AS [Connecting machine IP],
program_name,client_interface_name,login_name,nt_domain,nt_user_name, name as DatabaseName, 
sys.dm_exec_sessions.status AS [Session status],command,r.Status AS [Request Status],
last_request_start_time,last_request_end_time,sys.dm_exec_sessions.status,r.status, text, *
from sys.dm_exec_sessions inner join sys.dm_exec_connections on sys.dm_exec_sessions.session_id = sys.dm_exec_connections.session_id
inner join sys.dm_exec_requests r on sys.dm_exec_connections.connection_id = r.connection_id
inner join sys.databases on r.database_id = sys.databases.database_id
cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle)
```

Comment: What is the MS SQL Server version(x,y,z)?

Comment: thanks for the useful query. For my case,it's running in ~00:00:00 seconds.So,shouldn't be a problem to run in at every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

**It depends on the amount of connections and your hardware + your ability to change the query.**

*The first thing you should do is look at the query and decide which columns you need and which columns you don't need.*

If we run the query with

```
set statistics io, time on;
```

**On an idle server with < 100 connections**

```
select count(*) from sys.dm_exec_connections
```

**Result**

```
20
```

The result is clear:

```
 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 16 ms,  elapsed time = 18 ms.
```

The logicalreads are also very small (thanks [statisticsparser](http://statisticsparser.com/)):
[image]

This should mean that the query is harmless on this server,even if we run it every 5 seconds.

---

**On a prod server with over 10k connections**

```
select count(*) from sys.dm_exec_connections
```

**Result**

```
13713
```

[image]

Which means that every 5 seconds, around 300 - 400 ms cpu time will be used:

```
 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 422 ms,  elapsed time = 485 ms.
```

**And that amounts to the query running 1/10th of every 5 seconds.**

**However**, if you can change the query, either by omitting some columns, or using a temp table, the overhead could be lowered by a lot.

E.G. Splitting up the query in two parts and removing some columns.

```
set statistics io, time on;
select sys.dm_exec_sessions.session_id, host_name as [Connecting machine name], client_net_address AS [Connecting machine IP],
program_name,client_interface_name,login_name,nt_domain,nt_user_name, 
sys.dm_exec_sessions.status AS [Session status],command,r.Status AS [Request Status],
last_request_start_time,last_request_end_time,r.connection_id 
INTO #temp
from sys.dm_exec_sessions 
inner join sys.dm_exec_connections on sys.dm_exec_sessions.session_id = sys.dm_exec_connections.session_id
inner join sys.dm_exec_requests r on sys.dm_exec_connections.connection_id = r.connection_id


select #temp.session_id, #temp.[Connecting machine name], #temp.[Connecting machine IP],
program_name,client_interface_name,login_name,nt_domain,nt_user_name, name as DatabaseName, 
#temp.[Session status],#temp.command,r.Status AS [Request Status],
last_request_start_time,last_request_end_time,r.status, text,  *
FROM #temp 
inner join sys.dm_exec_requests r on #temp.connection_id = r.connection_id
inner join sys.databases on r.database_id = sys.databases.database_id
cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle)

DROP TABLE #temp
```

[image]

*Resulting in 10X lower amount of CPU usage.*

---

### Extra testing

**On a server with 600 connections**

```
select count(*) from sys.dm_exec_connections

600

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 31 ms,  elapsed time = 40 ms.
```

About twice as much cpu time as with 20 connections.

**Testing every 5 seconds on the idle server**

If we add two jobs that run every 10 seconds.

*(with 5 seconds between them because we cannot go lower than each 10 seconds scheduling.)*

[image]

And watch the result, The jobs started executing at ~9 AM on a server with **2 cores @3,5GHZ**:

[image]

The cpu usage difference is not visible, before and after the 9AM mark.

[image]

Server activity remains closely the same

[image]

DB IO.

[image]

Wait stats went up with a negligible 20ms on `ASYNC_NETWORK_IO`.

[image]